# Add Android support to Cordova project

Tags: android, macos, cordova

I have the following error while I'm building app on android in my Cordova project (I have the Android SDK downloaded). I'm running on Mac OS X

```
Creating android project...

/Users/me/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error: The command "android" failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your path.
at /Users/me/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:85:29
at _rejected (/Users/me/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
at /Users/me/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
at Promise.when (/Users/me/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/me/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
at /Users/me/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
at flush (/Users/me/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
Error: /Users/me/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)
```

Anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: You have this error when running `cordova platform add android`? Seems you did not add the android sdk to your path. The important part of the log is `Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your path.` (mostly the end of the sentance)

Comment: Yes, when ruuning `cordova platform add android`. 
How to add SDK to my path ?

Here is my .bash_profile :
`export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/me/adt-bundle/sdk"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools"`

Comment: and, if I type `android`, the Android SDK Manager run

Answer (score 2):

Ok, my bad the SDK is installed. Have you installed the SDK for API 19?

- Run the android sdk manager using the `android` command
- Find the group "Android 4.4.2 (API 19)
- Check the line "SDK pkatform"

Cordova 3.5 uses SDK 19 as target sdk (you can change it by editing androidmanifest.xml), so it's a requirement but that's not clearly explained and the error message is not clear either.

If you want to avoid a long time of downloading useless stuff, I would recommend you to uncheck everything about Android Wear (Android 4.4W) and Android L in the sdk manager before clicking the Install button.

All you really need is the SDK platform that matches with API 19, Android SDK tools, Android SDK platform tools, Android SDK Build-tools and maybe USB driver and Android support Library. Everything else can be safely unchecked if you want to save space/time.

When you get errors with android and cordova, there's a script you can try to get more details on the error. On OSX+cordova 3.5, it should be something like

```
$HOME/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/check_reqs
```

To install apache ant and add it to your path, update your .bash.profile :

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/me/adt-bundle/sdk"
export ANT_HOME="/Users/me/apache-ant"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANT_HOME/bin"
```

Comment: Okay thanks, so now I added android platform to my project :-)
**But**, when running `cordova emulate android` I'm getting this error :
`BUILD FAILED
/Users/me/adt-bundle/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/me/adt-bundle/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:698: null returned: 1

Total time: 3 seconds

/Users/me/Desktop/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126throw e;
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-f,/Users/me/Desktop/myApp/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen`

Comment: Have you downloaded apache ant and added it to your path?

Comment: I downloaded Apache Ant, but how to add it to my path?

Comment: I did exactly it in my .bash_profile but I'm getting `BUILD FAILED
/Users/me/adt-bundle/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/me/adt-bundle/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:698: null returned: 1
Total time: 1 second
/Users/me/Desktop/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126 throw e; Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-f,/Users/me/Desktop/myApp/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: /Users/me/Desktop/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 8`

Comment: Note: if I do `$HOME/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/check_reqs` I'm getting the proof that android should work : `Looks like your environment fully supports cordova-android development!`

Comment: Can you try to run just `cordova build android`? to check if the error is when building or when runing the emulator.